# Azure Stream Analytics - Last Event compare with the stream of input data for specific interval

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

Can anyone help me to get the following scenario with the sample query. I have added my sample code at the end but it never worked. I am new to stream analytics and your help will be greatly appreciated.

1) Get the last event of the incoming input Group by CARID (by timestamp)

2) Read the speed of the last event for each CARID

3) Check if the last event speed (of each CARID) with the input data stream received for last 12 seconds

4) If the Last event speed is less, then send to the output otherwise, don't process the last event (again, it should be by CARID)

I used TubmlingWindow function to get the event stream for the past seconds.

Here is the sample code i used:

```
 WITH LastInWindow AS
(
    SELECT 
        CARID,
        MAX(cast(timestamp as datetime)) AS LastEventTime
    FROM 
        IoTHubInput   
    GROUP BY 
        TumblingWindow(second, 12) , CARID       
),

InputLog AS
(
    SELECT 
       CARID,
       max(Speed) speed
    FROM 
        IoTHubLog  

    GROUP BY 
        TumblingWindow(second, 12),timestamp,CARID
)

SELECT
IoTHubLog.CARID,   
IoTHubLog.Speed   
 INTO Outputlog
FROM
    IoTHubLog  
    INNER JOIN LastInWindow
    ON DATEDIFF(second, IoTHubLog, LastInWindow) BETWEEN 0 AND 12
    AND cast( IoTHubLog.timestamp as datetime)=LastInWindow.LastEventTime  
     AND IoTHubLog.CARID = LastInWindow.CARID
    INNER JOIN InputLog
    ON DATEDIFF(second, IoTHubLog, InputLog) BETWEEN 0 AND 12
    AND  cast(IoTHubLog.timestamp as datetime)> cast( InputLog.timestamp as datetime)
    AND IoTHubLog.CARID = InputLog.CARID
    AND  InputLog.speed >   IoTHubLog.speed  

    GROUP BY 
        TumblingWindow(second, 1), IoTHubLog.CARID
```

Comment: An explanation is a bit hard to understand. So, you want to get the last carId speed that was received in the last 12 seconds, and put to the output every event from the input(in the last 12 seconds) which has the speed less than the last event speed? Or? And what is InputLog from your code - IoT Hub input, or?

Comment: Hi, I want to compare the last event (by latest timestamp) speed with the recent events received for  the time window of 12 seconds (less than the last event timestamp) . if the last event speed is less than the speed received in the 12 second window, i will process it to the output. All these logic needs to be grouped by CARID. So, there could be many events recieved at the same timestamp by CarID. All should be sent to the output if they satisfy the above rule. Please let me know if you need more info.